# JDBC RDD Query Statement without '?'

Tags: sql, scala, jdbc, apache-spark, rdd

I am using Spark with Scala and trying to get data from a database using JdbcRDD.

```
val rdd = new JdbcRDD(sparkContext,
    driverFactory,
    testQuery,
    rangeMinValue.get,
    rangeMaxValue.get,
    partitionCount,
    rowMapper)
    .persist(StorageLevel.MEMORY_AND_DISK)
```

Within the query there are no ? values to set (since the query is quite long I am not putting it here.) So I get an error saying that,

*java.sql.SQLException: Parameter index out of range (1 > number of parameters, which is 0).*

I have no idea what the problem is. Can someone suggest any kind of solution ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is Spark expected that your query String has a couple of ? parameters.

From Spark user list:

> In order for Spark to split the JDBC query in parallel, it expects an
>   upper and lower bound for your input data, as well as a number of
>   partitions so that it can split the query across multiple tasks.
>
> For example, depending on your data distribution, you could set an
>   upper and lower bound on your timestamp range, and spark should be
>   able to create new sub-queries to split up the data.
>
> Another option is to load up the whole table using the HadoopInputFormat
>   class of your database as a NewHadoopRDD.

Comment: So in the case that for a specific query to be handled with a single partition if I set it to one in the Constructor of JdbcRDD it will not split it and the bounds will be min and max values ? @gasparms

Comment: I don't understand, if you want Spark to take min and max values you should create a query like "SELECT * FROM student_info WHERE id >= ? AND id <= ?".  ? will be replaced by min and max value.

Answer (score 3):

Got the same problem.
Used this:

```
SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE ... AND ? = ?
```

And then call it with lowerbound 1, higher bound 1 and partition 1. 
Will always run only one partition.